# On the Convergence of Lower Semicontinuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a nonnegative measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow[0,\infty]$, can we always find a decreasing sequence of lower semicontinuous functions $(\varphi_{n})$ such that $\varphi_{n}\geq f$ and that $\varphi_{n}(x)\downarrow f(x)$ a.e.?

Note that by a theorem of Baire, an upper semicontinuous function is the limit of a decreasing sequence of extended real-valued continuous functions, but this does not address my question because $f$ is not assumed to be upper semicontinuous.

I also notice that asking for $\varphi_{n}(x)\downarrow f(x)$ **everywhere** certainly required too much and most probably not true, so I relax the condition that being almost everywhere convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $S=\{f<\infty\}$. By Lusin’s theorem (and $\sigma$-compactness of $\mathbb R^n$) you have an increasing sequence of compact sets $A_n\subseteq S$ with $S\backslash\bigcup_n A_n$ a nullset, such that $f$ is uniformly continuous on each $A_n$.  Define $\varphi_n$ to equal $f$ on $A_n$ and $\infty$ elsewhere.

##### Update

The aforementioned answer is a little unsatisfying, as we may wish to have $\varphi_n$ finite almost everywhere, provided $f$ has that property.

To do this, for each $n$, choose (by the Borel regularity of Lebesgue measure) an open $U_n\supseteq \{f>n\}$ such that $m(U_n\backslash \{f>n\})<\frac{1}{n}$ (we may take $U_0=\mathbb R^n$), and $U_{n+1}\subseteq U_n$.  Let $\varphi=\sum_n\chi_{U_n}$.

We argue that $\varphi$ is lower-semicontinuous, is never less than $f$, and is finite almost everywhere that $f$ is.  Indeed, lower semi-continuity follows immediately from the fact that for each $t$, $\{\phi>t\} = U_{\lfloor{t}\rfloor}$, which is open.  By construction it is never less than $f$, and finally, at any point $x$ where $f(x)$ is finite, if $\varphi(x)=\infty$ we must eventually have $x\in U_n\backslash \{f>n\}$ for each sufficiently large $n$, and the intersection of these sets has $0$ measure by construction.

Now we choose $A_n\subseteq S=\{f<\infty\}$ as in the original answer, but this time define $\varphi_n$ to equal $f$ on $A_n$, and $\varphi$ elsewhere.

Comment: The construction of such $\varphi_{n}$ is upper semicontinuous rather than lower semicontinuous because the characteristic functions are taken on compact sets?

Comment: We are not taking characteristic functions.  $\varphi_n$ is infinite on an open set, then drops to equal $f$ on a closed set.  This is lower semicontinuous.  To see this, if $x_k\to x$, then $\varphi_n(x_k)$ can only drop to $\varphi_n(x)=f(x)$.  It can never jump, since it is infinite only on an open set.

Comment: Okay, that works. But I never expect that $\varphi_{n}$ takes "too much" places on $\infty$, in other words, can we further ask for $\varphi_{n}$ being finite a.e. also?

Comment: @user284331 I updated to address your question.